# Autocorrect & Capitalization of Words in iOS13

Tags: keyboard, autocorrect, ios

Since upgrading to iOS 13 I've noticed that every time I type my name (primarily in Messages and Mail apps) auto-correct insists on fully capitalizing my name (James > JAMES) whereas before it would only capitalize the first letter. I don't know why it has suddenly started doing this and can't find any way to 'reset' the auto-correct dictionary. Turning off auto-correction in Keyboard settings doesn't make any difference to this behaviour. Any advice on how to fix this annoying feature?

Comment: have you disabled Auto Capitalization from General -> Keyboard.

Comment: try creating a text replacement for James -> James and JAMES -> James.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve turned off Auto-Correction in Settings > General > Keyboard. The capitalized suggestion JAMES still appears, but the phone doesn’t automatically replace it.

Comment: I've noticed that autocorrect will take "hints" on some words from non obvious places, like contacts, and specifically from nicknames or aliases. Maybe you have JAMES on all caps somewhere on your contacts?